# Indicated composite function?

Tags: calculus

Please i really need help, I have my problem below and also my solution 
I've  tried

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You didn't expand $2(x-2)^2$ correctly. Here is the answer for part a.

$\begin{align}2(x-2)^2-3(x-2)+1&=2(x^2-4x+4)-3x+6+1\\&=2x^2-\color{red}8x+\color{red}8-3x+7\\&=2x^2-11x+15\end{align}$

I suggest you take a look at part b yourself.